# How do I loop through and change values in this PHP object?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is a fairly big object dumped using print_r.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/175RLhWlMQcyhGR6ffGSsoJGS3RyloEqo4EEHCL2H2vg/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to change the values of the uploaded_files.

Towards the end of that object you'll see something like

> [uploaded_files] => Array
>       (
>           [attachment] => /home2/magician/public_html/development/testing/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads/Central-Coast-Montessori-logo.jpg
>           [attachment2] => /home2/magician/public_html/development/testing/wp-content/uploads/wpcf7_uploads/Andrew.jpg )

My code
        // move the attachments to wpcf7ev temp folder

> ```
> foreach ($cf7ev_object['uploaded_files'] as $key => $uploaded_file_path) {
>     $new_filepath = WPCF7EV_UPLOADS_DIR . '/' . basename($uploaded_file_path);
>     wpcf7ev_debug("New file path is {$new_filepath}");
>     rename($uploaded_file_path, $new_filepath);
>     wpcf7ev_debug("'{$key}'is the KEY for {$uploaded_file_path}");
>     wpcf7ev_debug($cf7ev_object['uploaded_files']);        
>     $cf7ev_object['uploaded_files'][$key] = $new_filepath; // this is not updating
> }
> ```

To loop through it I have been using

```
    foreach ($cf7ev_object->uploaded_files as $key => $uploaded_file_path) {
```

and this has worked.

But shouldn't it be

```
    foreach ($cf7ev_object['uploaded_files'] as $key => $uploaded_file_path) {
```

? As '->' is for accessing methods?

And specifically I want to update the values of those uploaded_files, so to do that I need to do

```
        $cf7ev_object['uploaded_files'][$key] = $new_filepath; // this is not updating
```

? But this doesn't seem to be working.

I think I need to be clear on how to access values in an object.

Thanks.

Comment: you can loop through the foreach

Comment: you tried to make the object an array in your last example.. Play with my solution, that should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, regarding the single arrow "->" that is how you reference an objects values. But I won't get into that.  Since you say it works, $cf7ev_object is obviously an object.

You say you want to "access the values in the object".

```
var_dump($cf7ev_object);
```

This will spit out what is in that object.  I gather you are a bit of a newbie, so I will try to help you out best I can with the limited data you provided (you may want to expand your question.

Looping is not a one-shot deal.  You can have nested loops and nested loops inside of those.  However, it is a resource hog if you're not careful.  Here  is an exercise that might help you.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($cf7ev_object->uploaded_files as $key => $value) {
  $new_value = $value;//do something to the $value here
  $new_array[$key] = $new_value;
}
//take a look at your work now:
print_r($new_array);
```

I hope this helps.  Note: your google doc is restricted, public can't see it.. And your question is too vague.  Let me know if I can help more.

If you want to change the object array values instantly you just set it equal to the above loop result:

```
$cf7ev_object->uploaded_files = $new_array;
```

Comment: Apparently anyone could access that doc who has the link. I've updated it to be publicly accessible.

Comment: So [uploaded_files] is one of the object's values yes? So to access it I would use $cf7ev_object->uploaded_files over $cf7ev_object['uploaded_files']?

Comment: yes that is correct, do exactly what I did in my solution.  it is what you are looking for.  you can access an object as-if it were an array.